# ETH sent to incorrect address

Tags: addresses, public-key, address.transfer

I've recently started looking at blockchain so have bought a small amount of bitcoin and ethereum to allow me to understand the processes. I may have some ETH but would appreciate some help as it seems to be in the wrong place!

I purchased the ETH through bittylicious after first generating a wallet using myetherwallet. I could see the transaction in the bittylicious history but not in myeytherwallet? Looking a bit more closely, I can see that while the public key of the wallet generated starts 0xf36Bxxx, the transaction shows the funds transferred to 0xf368xxx. That's an "8" where it should be a "B" for anyone else who should be wearing their glasses when using their laptop!

So, the funds are in the 0xf368xxx wallet (let's assume I gave the wrong key) and would like them in 0xf36Bxxx which is the 'real' wallet created in myetherwallet, but I'm not sure if I can move them without the private key related to 0xf368xxx? Is there any hope for me?

(yes, I'm expecting that £30 of lost ETH is the price of a very valuable lesson, but any help's appreciated!)

UPDATE:
thanks for the replies, as expected, it seems I can't get at the funds sent to an incorrect address which I gave.

Maybe someone with knowledge could help me with something which is puzzling me though?

I accidentally gave out an address for the ETH to be sent to which was identical in every way to my actual address apart from the 6th digit was given as "8" instead of "B". That's 41 out of 42 upper/lower/numeric characters being the same. So my question is whether there is any address validation in ethereum when ETH is sent to another party? My novice understanding is that hash, signature and private keys related to the ether wallet address ought to make it difficult to send to a wallet which doesn't exist, and the chances of another wallet existing with the same address as mine apart from one character being 8 instead of B ought to be infinitesimally small?

So my question is now not can I retrieve my ETH from a known address which is almost identical to mine, but can an ethereum transaction be created which posts to a wallet with any random address (which may not be a real wallet address at all?).

Apologies if this is really basic stuff I'm asking, but what are the odds of two 42-digit wallet addresses differing in only one character (and that character appearing as similar as 8 and B)?

I have looked at etherscan.io and can see both the empty wallet and the one which received the funds.

Thanks again for any assistance.

Comment: Put your wallet address here to check TX

Answer (score 1):

in cryptocurrency field you can't refund money, am sorry for this.
you can check TX in your wallet by paste your address wallet in [etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/)